# OSX ForceFeedback Driver

Tags: macos, usb, device-driver, hid

I've had this old gamepad for a while now, the GameStop Advanced Controller (it's actually one of those mass produced generic devices from a company called DragonRise inc.), which comes with a rumble/haptics feature. Unfortunately it doesn't work on OSX. I figured this would be a nice project to learn more about driver development on OSX and USB HID devices in general. Now, the gamepad itself works fine as a standard HID device, except for the haptics/force feedback stuff. My goal is to write a simple ForceFeedback plugin for the gamepad.

What I've done so far, is to create a very simple IOKit driver which inherits from IOUSBHIDDevice and basically lets the super class do most of the grunt work; my reasoning was, it works fine now, I just want to *add* functionality. So that sort of worked; my problem now is that the driver is being added as a new interface to the device in the registry. It is matched, but not used. Ideally I'd want to completely replace the generic IOUSBHIDDevice class as the IOClass for that specific gamepad, but I'm not sure how.

On the other hand, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, and I don't need to create a new driver to add a ForceFeedback plugin for that gamepad; that's just the solution I came up with after reading the documentation.

Here's the Info.plist (the important parts anyway) I have for my driver project:

```
<key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
<dict>
    <key>IODragonRiseGenericUSB</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
        <string>name_npp_driver_IODragonRiseGenericUSB</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
        <key>IOKitDebug</key>
        <integer>65535</integer>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>name_npp_driver_IODragonRiseGenericUSB</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>name.npp.driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
        <key>IOCFPlugInTypes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>F4545CE5-BF5B-11D6-A4BB-0003933E3E3E</key>
            <string>IODragonRiseGenericUSB.kext/Contents/PlugIns/ForceFeedback.plugin</string>
        </dict>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>6</integer>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>121</integer>
        <key>HIDDefaultBehavior</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>bInterfaceClass</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>bInterfaceProtocol</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>bInterfaceSubClass</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>Copyright © 2013 npepinpe. All rights reserved.</string>
<key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily</key>
    <string>1.7.1</string>
    <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</key>
    <string>5.1</string>
    <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver</key>
    <string>5.0</string>
    <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
    <string>11.4.2</string>
    <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
    <string>11.4.2</string>
</dict>
```

Something to note, I tried changing the IOProviderClass to USBInterface (as the IOUSBHIDDevice does), but then my device is simply not matched at all, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

So my question is, how do I replace the default IOUSBHIDDriver that is matched for my particular gamepad with my custom driver? Or is that not the right approach if I just want to add a ForceFeedback plugin (but do not need to change any other behavior)?

Comment: what precisely is your question here?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question wasn't exactly crystal clear. I've edited it, hopefully that's better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of what the old Logitech Force Feedback has as one of its IOKit personalities:

```
<key>Logitech Cordless RumblePad</key>
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver</string>
 <key>IOCFPlugInTypes</key>
 <dict>
  <key>F4545CE5-BF5B-11D6-A4BB-0003933E3E3E</key>
  <string>LogitechForceFeedback.kext/Contents/PlugIns/WMJoyFrc.plugin</string>
 </dict>
 <key>IOClass</key>
 <string>IOUSBHIDDriver</string>
 <key>IOProviderClass</key>
 <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
 <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
 <integer>1</integer>
 <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
 <integer>0</integer>
 <key>idProduct</key>
 <integer>49681</integer>
 <key>idVendor</key>
 <integer>1133</integer>
</dict>
```

I think you only need to focus on the Force Feedback bundle (that's what the Logitech Kext is: just the info.plist and the Force Feedback bundle).

The Mac XBox 360 driver has a force feedback driver. You can use that as a starting point.